Pros and Cons Using Bayesian Metrics or Time Series Approach?
I have two years' worth of sales data for a range of products, including:
Sales: Total sales revenue
Usage Time: Total usage time in hours
Reviews: Numeric ratings and textual reviews from users
I'm interested in identifying underperforming products based on these variables. So far, I'm considering two approaches:

Bayesian Metrics: Creating a Bayesian model to assess whether a product's performance is within its expected range.

Time Series Analysis: Forecasting sales counts and analyzing trends to determine if a product's performance is trending up or down.


Specific Questions:
What are the pros and cons of using a Bayesian approach versus a time series approach for this problem?
Additionally, feel free to point me to textbooks or resources that cover these approaches.
